# Call Script from Watch in Linux

Tags: node.js, gulp

I’m having trouble calling a script on linux with a watch function.

Here is snippet of code:

```
function generateDjangoRenderedHtml() {
  return gulp
    .task('task', function (cb) {
      exec('./django/django_gen_static_website', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        console.log(stderr);
        cb(err);
       });
     })
}
 
function watchChanges() {
      ...
      gulp.watch("./django/yWebsiteProj/src/yPatentWebsiteProj/templates/site/*.html",   generateDjangoRenderedHtml);
      ...
      
     }
```

When I change one of the html files, I get the message:

> [11:55:15] Starting 'generateDjangoRenderedHtml'...

but nothing happens.  If I look at the rendered html, I can see the script is not being called.

I tried to use spawn but got the same result.  I also tried to full path to the script.

If I run the script from a command line (i.e., ./django/django_gen_static_website) the script works as expected.

I’m running Rocky Linux 9 (RHEL 9 clone) and I’m using Node.js 6.14.11

Any suggestions on debugging this?